glxinfo gives odd error on ubuntu noble container
I'm trying to create a ubuntu noble container (it has to be ubuntu noble due to another software's compatibility constraints) with a gui capable of running Gazebo, a robot simulation. For Gazebo, I need a working OpenGL setup (using mesa). As of now, though, my attempts to verify my setup with glxinfo fail due to some odd error:
root@554bf70792e2:/# glxinfo
name of display: :1
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

I've done a ton of searching online and tried many solutions but none of them seemed to work. Can anyone help me out?
Further context
I'm running this on an apple silicon macbook (M3).
Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 ubuntu:noble

# ---------- Set Up VNC Server ----------

# Install Necessary Debian Packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractivex
RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver dbus-x11

# Add vncuser
RUN useradd -m vncuser && echo "vncuser:password" | chpasswd

# Switch to vncuser
USER vncuser

# Set up VNC password

RUN mkdir -p ~/.vnc && \
    echo "password" | vncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd && \
    chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd

# Set the default desktop environment to XFCE
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\nXvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x720x24 &\nstartxfce4 &" > ~/.vnc/xstartup && \
    chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup && \
    touch ~/.Xauthority

# Switch back to root
USER root

# Expose VNC port
EXPOSE 5901

# Set environment variables
ENV DISPLAY=:1 \
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/runtime-root \
    LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

# Mesa and other libraries
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-dri \
    libglx-mesa0 \
    libegl-mesa0 \
    mesa-vulkan-drivers \
    libosmesa6 \
    mesa-utils \
    xvfb \
    pciutils

vnc-start.sh:
su - vncuser -c "
export USER=vncuser
export DISPLAY=:1
vncserver -geometry 1280x720 -depth 24 :1
xhost +"

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  gprp:
    build: .
    container_name: gprp
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    ports:
      - "5901:5901"
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace

To reach this error, I run docker-compose build and docker-compose up -d, then (within the container) run vnc-start.sh and glxinfo.
What I've tried
Other than just trying to install more libraries (just in case) I really have no idea what to try. Descriptions of this error online seem to stem from cases that don't really match mine, and are often fixed simply by reinstalling libraries (even though that doesn't seem to make a difference for me).
